# How do you tell type from VisualStudio debugger's Datatip?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a feeling the answer to this is either "you can't" or it will be embarrassingly obvious, but when you hover a variable in the VS (2015) debugger, how do you know what type it is?

[image: VS2015 debugger datatip]

In this case, it's `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, but I only know that because I checked it in the Watch window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTips just provide a convenient way to view information about variables in your program during debugging, it doesn't have a column to show the type of the variables, we often add them to other debugger windows like Watch windows or others if you really want to view more detailed information about it.

But I think it is a good feature request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16283041-show-the-type-from-visualstudio-debugger-datatip